# Why the CPU compiles the GPU shader?

Tags: caching, compilation, shader, gpu, cpu

To understand in general how GPU's cache support work, I read some information and understood this:

CPU compiles shader and transmit resulting code of shader to GPU to execute and also save it to the disk.

If necessary to execute the same shader, GPU get it saved binary code directly from the disk.

if I understood correctly, I don't understand why CPU compiles shader each time.

Unless the shader is not compiled before runtime (that is during development)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all GPUs use the same instruction set. Having only the binary on disk means that the sets of GPU architectures that can be used with that software will be fixed forever.

Comment: thanks, Is it means that shader's compiled code is intermediate code (e.g. as java bytecode)?

Comment: thanks, I just didn't understand this point that the CPU compiles a shader for a specific GPU, now I know